# WinError 32 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process cannot delete file through python or manually

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hi guys I have a program which creates and saves an xlsx file, then opens it and converts to pdf...but then I want it to delete the original xlsx file.

1. it creates both files in the right directory.
2. However it does not delete the xlsx nor can I delete it manually as it says the file is still open

```
        wb.save(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)


        #this should turn the xlsx into a pdf
        xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
        ws2 = books.Worksheets[0]
        ws2.Visible = 1
        save_the_pdf = NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_pdf
        ws2.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,save_the_pdf)

        #this removes the xlsx file
        os.remove(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
```

My hunch is that i haven't used .close() in the right place and that its just left the excel file open. I have tried...

```
        wb.save(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
        wb.close()


        #this should turn the xlsx into a pdf
        xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
        ws2 = books.Worksheets[0]
        ws2.Visible = 1
        save_the_pdf = NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_pdf
        ws2.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,save_the_pdf)


        #this removes the xlsx file
        os.remove(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
```

to no avail. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

-update-

I have identified the problem to be in these lines ...

```
#this should turn the xlsx into a pdf
        xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
        ws2 = books.Worksheets[0]
        ws2.Visible = 1
        save_the_pdf = NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_pdf
        ws2.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,save_the_pdf)
```

The xlsx file remains open and wont let me delete it via code...same with deleting the xlsx file manually. I have to double click the file to open it, then close it before I can delete.

How can I close the xlsx file at the end of this code?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to check task manager if there are still instances open if you're unable to delete it manually.

Comment: thanks, I did and it said excel wasn't on

Comment: You need to close the Workbook that you open with `xlApp`.

Comment: I figured that...any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At ease guys....as I thought I hadn't closed it properly. The code below works brilliantly.

Damn, I hate being stuck for days.

```
#this should turn the xlsx into a pdf
        xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
        ws2 = books.Worksheets[0]
        ws2.Visible = 1
        save_the_pdf = NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_pdf
        ws2.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,save_the_pdf)
        books.Close(True) # save the workbook

        #this removes the xlsx file
        os.remove(NEW_RECEIPT_PATH + new_file_name_xlsx)
```